# How to apply for an IRCTC Refund?

Tags: refunds, tatkal, irctc

I needed to book a [Tatkal Ticket](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/tatkal_Scheme.html) for Indian Railways using IRCTC website today. During the booking process, the website showed 242 seats as available. However, due to slower than usual payment gateway, the payment process took a long time. Eventually my payment went through successfully and I was redirected to IRCTC to complete the booking process. But the website flashed a message saying `Reservation Failed. No seats available`. This meant that even though my account had been debited, no ticket was booked for me.

Now I want the money back. I checked for the `Refund Request` option which I am unable to find on the site. I tried calling the Customer Service numbers listed on the site but gcouldn't connect. I sent an e-mail regarding the issue to `care@irctc.co.in` and `eticket@irctc.co.in` describing this issue. However, again I only got automated responses.

How do I proceed to get a refund from IRCTC?

Comment: You can Use the "My Transaction" menu option in the top navigation bar (The one that also has sign-out/contact-us button). There you can see "Last Transaction detail" and "Failed Transaction History". Normally if payment is debited and seat is not booked, IRCTC automatically processes the refunds (though it may take 3-5 days for it to be credited back in your bank account)

Comment: The problem is IRCTC use a third party payment gateway fssnet. In last transaction details, even if the payment failed , it will show the amount. So how do I know whether the amount reached from the third party to IRCTC?

Comment: IIRC it also shows the refund status. When you click on the transaction ID it opens a pop-up that shows all the details.

Comment: You must apply for TDR that will automatic refund you money with some amount deduct as a service charge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @Dorothy worth explaining WHY you're closing it as off topic, when you do so.

Comment: @lambshaanxy any specific reason for the +500 bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Some General Information in this topic

Indian Railway accept online as well as offline ticket reservation for General and Tatkal tickets.

The Speciality of Tatkal means, the reservation start only 11:00 AM IST one day before the journey.

That is, if I want to travel on 05-04-2017, I can book only on or after 11:00 AM on 04-04-2017.

There is no refund on Confirmed Tatkal tickets. But for Waitlisted Tatkal tickets, the refund will be done (refund amount = ticket amount - 60 ).

#### Now, the question

I talked to some railway staffs whom I know personally know, about this and they told that if the reservation is failed, the refund process will be done automatically since it is done via Online.

Since I directly paid with Debit Card with pin, the refund amount will be automatically transferred to my bank.

When I checked the failed ticket history, it shows **Payment settled**. Now I have a proof that they received the amount.

The railway staff told me that it may take upto 7 days for the amount to get refunded.

Later when I checked ( after 5 days, the **Refund status show refunded**).

[image]

So, for bookings via IRCTC, if failed, refund will be done automatically.

#### For your information

If the ticket booking is successful but is waitlisted and didn't get confirmed before the journey, the refund will be done automatically within 7 days after the journey. Because of that, **Waitlisted Online tickets can't be used to travel in General Compartment. Whereas offline waitlisted tickets can be used to travel in General Compartments**